# CDI: 2 projects, @Inject -> (WELD-001408) error

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, cdi

I try to inject a bean into a portlet. Both are located in separated projects. 
Iam using JBoss 7.1.1 and Liferay6.2 SDK. This is the simplest scenario I can imagine but I still get this error. It works fine if the bean is localted in the same war.

**Error:**

> 10:31:30,704 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."DWPortlet1-portlet.war".WeldService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."DWPortlet1-portlet.war".WeldService: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Calc] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private de.pao.bean.DWPortletController.calc]
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:83)
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
>   Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Calc] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private de.pao.bean.DWPortletController.calc]
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:275)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:244)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:107)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:127)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:346)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:331)
>       at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:366)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldContainer.start(WeldContainer.java:83)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.services.WeldService.start(WeldService.java:76)
>       ... 5 more

**Bean:**

```
> package com.test;

import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Calc {

    public Calc() {
    }

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }

    public int mult(int a, int b) {
        return a*b;
    }

}
```

**Portlet:**

```
> 
package de.pao.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;    
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;    
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;    
import com.test.Calc;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class DWPortletController implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("1234");
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2056281697556539581L;

    @Inject private Session0Bean sb0;
    @Inject private Calc calc;

    public DWPortletController() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void buttonAction() {
        log.info("Hallo");
        sb0.sayHello();
        log.info("2+2 = " + calc.add(2, 2));
    }
}
```

**jboss-deployment-strucutre.xml:** (under /portlet/docroot/WEB-INF):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.liferay.portal" />
            <module name="javax.annotation.api" />
            <module name="javax.enterprise.api" />
            <module name="javax.inject.api" />
            <module name="javax.interceptor.api" />
            <module name="javax.validation.api" />
            <module name="javax.mail.api" />
            <module name="org.jboss.modules" />
            <module name="deployment.BeanLogic.jar"  />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**ivy-xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<ivy-module
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
>
    <info module="portlet_primefaces_tmpl" organisation="com.liferay" />

    <dependencies defaultconf="default">
        <dependency name="jboss-el" org="org.jboss.el" rev="2.0.1.GA" />
        <dependency name="jsf-api" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.1.27" />
        <dependency name="jsf-impl" org="com.sun.faces" rev="2.1.27" />
        <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-api" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
        <dependency name="liferay-faces-bridge-impl" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
        <dependency name="liferay-faces-portal" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
        <dependency name="liferay-faces-util" org="com.liferay.faces" rev="3.2.4-ga5" />
        <dependency name="cdi-portlet-bridge-shared" org="com.liferay.cdi" rev="6.2.0.2" />     
        <dependency name="primefaces" org="org.primefaces" rev="4.0" />
        <dependency org="org.jboss.weld" name="weld-api" rev="1.1.Final" />
        <dependency org="org.jboss.weld" name="weld-core" rev="1.1.16.Final" />
        <dependency org="org.jboss.weld" name="weld-spi" rev="1.1.Final" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

What am I doing wrong?